# Check for the existence of any other POST variable that it is not the required one

Tags: php

I noticed (reading logs of websites I administer), hackers try to submit post requests, literally "inventing" post variables names.

Some website features old PHP code, eg.

```
if (isset($_POST["mail"]) && !empty($_POST["mail"])) {
    //...  
}else{  
    exit;
}
```

This basically checks if there is a $_POST variable "mail" and it is not empty.

Is it possible to check for the existence of any $_POST variable that it is NOT "mail" and exit the script in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to check for differences:

```
$whitelist = ['mail' => null];

$hasOthers = !empty(array_diff_key($whitelist, $_POST));
```

Comment: Ok, this is exactly what I was looking for!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a different way using filters and not accesing directly to $_POST.
At first, you have to create a definition of what $_POST elements you are interested in. So you have to create an array with the corresponding filters, as example for login definition

```
$definition = array(
    ["mail"] => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
    ["passwd"] => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
);
```

Next you can filter all the desirable $_POST elements with [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)

```
$desirablePost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $definition);
```

And finalyly you can filter again all the $_POST values usign a filter constant (remembering that all $_POST elements are strings).

```
$allPost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

So, to know if someone has injected another $_POST fields, we can compare the count() of both arrays.

```
if(count($desirablePost) !== count($allPost)){
    //error or exit(1) ...
}
```